# Asp.net Core REST API The LINQ expression Could not be Translated

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, linq, asp.net-core

Asp.net REST API , The LINQ expression could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'

```
    var query = from orders in DbContext.JobOrders where orders.OrderStat == 1
                            join users in DbContext.users on orders.Uid equals users.Uid into ousers
                            from onusers in ousers.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            join customers in DbContext.customers on orders.Uid equals customers.Uid into offlinecustomers
                            from offusers in offlinecustomers.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            join orderitems in DbContext.OrderItems on orders.Eid equals orderitems.OrderId into orderitems
                            from orderitem in orderitems.DefaultIfEmpty().GroupBy(i => i.OrderId).Select(g => new { qty = g.Sum(s => s.Qty == null ? 0 : s.Qty) })
                            select new
                            {
                                Eid = orders.Eid,
                                Uid = orders.Uid,
                                OrderStat = orders.OrderStat,
                                Name = onusers.Name == null ? offusers.Name : onusers.Name,
                                Contact = onusers.Contact == null ? offusers.Contact : onusers.Contact,
                                Qty = orderitem.qty
                            };
```

The code works fine if I remove orederitems table querying including group by clause.

The exact same code was working in asp.net and stopped working when I moved to asp.net Core.

Please Help

Comment: Check the dbmx mapping file to see if there are differences.  Did you do a clean build after upgrading?

Comment: I created a complete new project and copied the query only, its working if I remove query related to order items table

Comment: What database are you using?  Did you check the logs in the database to get more info on error?  You are getting a runtime error which is occurring in the database.

Comment: @jdweng MS SQL Database

Comment: Check the error logs by using SQL Server Management Studio and looking under the Management tab.

Comment: this works if I remove ".GroupBy(i => i.OrderId).Select(g => new { qty = g.Sum(s => s.Qty == null ? 0 : s.Qty) })" , but returns records of each entry

Comment: I need one line of data for each orderID to be returned with Sum(qty) field

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
var query = (from orders in DbContext.JobOrders where orders.OrderStat == 1
                            join users in DbContext.users on orders.Uid equals users.Uid into ousers
                            from onusers in ousers.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            join customers in DbContext.customers on orders.Uid equals customers.Uid into offlinecustomers
                            from offusers in offlinecustomers.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            join orderitems in DbContext.OrderItems on orders.Eid equals orderitems.OrderId into orderitems
                            from orderitem in orderitems.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            select new {orderitem = orderitem, users = users, onusers = onusers, offusers = offusers}
                            ).GroupBy(i => i.orderitem.OrderId)
                            .Select(g => new { 
                                orderId = g.Key,
                                qty = g.orderitem.Sum(s => s.qty == null ? 0 : s.qty),
                                Eid = g.orders.FirstOrDefault().Eid,
                                Uid = g.orders.FirstOrDefault().Uid,
                                OrderStat = g.orders.FirstOrDefault().OrderStat,
                                Name = g.onusers.FirstOrDefault().Name == null ? g.offusers.FirstOrDefault().Name : g.onusers.FirstOrDefault().Name,
                                Contact = g.onusers.FirstOrDefault().Contact == null ? g.offusers.FirstOrDefault().Contact : g.onusers.FirstOrDefaut().Contact
                            });
```

Comment: CS1061 'IGrouping<int, <anonymous type: OrderItem orderitem, User onusers, Customer offusers>>' does not contain a definition for 'orderitem' and no accessible extension method 'orderitem' accepting a first argument of type 'IGrouping<int, <anonymous type: OrderItem orderitem, User onusers, Customer offusers>>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Myapiv3
C:\..\JobOrdersController.cs
1356
Active

Comment: I copied the syntax from your code.  Maybe a typo.  In the GroupBy retype the i.orderitem.OrderId and see what selections VS picks for the properties.  I think the error is in the "join orderitems" and the line after with the DefaultEmpty.  Compare with the other join statements.  There is an inconsistency. Then make the GroupBy consistent with the fix.